# How to remove \n from string while post data to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, asihttprequest

I am converting an array into json and sending it to the server.

Here is my code for converting array into json:

```
NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr    
options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString  *finalJsonString= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", finalJsonString);
```

I have checked finalJsonString is a valid json. Here is the code for post the value to the server:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.delegate = self;
[request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"content-type" value:@"application/json"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:[finalJsonString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: 
[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]forKey:@"order"];
```

but when i print my request it gives me:

```
`key = order;
value = "[\n  \"1\",\n  \"2\",\n  \"3\"\n]";`
```

Which is not a valid json.

I have tried "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" method also but that did not work either. The problem only while sending request. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: its a valid string, but objective c internally add the \ for adding the " and \ character.

Comment: You don't need to delete \n symbols, they are converted back to line feeds on server side

Comment: but when i checked in json validater it is not a valid string

Comment: Correct, a Jason validator will reject the literal \n, but what is actually sent to the server is a new line character which is valid.

Comment: is \"1\" will also work?